# jQuery toggle form down if it does not get submitted due to validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a jquery toggle menu with some password fields.

```
$(function(){
  $(".expand_password_edit_form").on("click", function(event){
  $(".password-edit").find('.password').slideToggle(400,
    function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.password').offset().top + $('window').height()
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

But if the form does not get submitted, due to some validation errors, the menu is toggled up by default, so the user can't see the actual error labels on these fields.

What could be a workaround here?

Answer (score 2):

Your can place some data attribute at your HTML code, if validation failes.

```
<div class="#{record.valid? ? '' :'expand_password_edit_form'}" data-invalid=true>
...
</div>
```

And then, using javascript you can check, if this attribute is set - toggle down menu.

```
if $('.expand_password_edit_form').data('invalid')
  // toggle down
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
<div class="password" style="<%= "display:none;" unless f.object.errors.present? %>; height:260px;">
```